# Supersymmetry calculations using computer algebra

Tags: resource-recommendations, supersymmetry, software, supergravity

Already the early papers on supergravity were written using computer algebra software to do some calculations. What modern packages do people normally use for doing such calculations? Of course Mathematica and presumable a lot of other programs can be made to do such calculations, I am wondering if there are special packages or tutorials how to do such calculations in them.

Comment: Hi orbifold - as originally posted, this sounded like a list question. I've made a little edit that makes it a little more focused. I'm not sure if it's appropriate in this form (as it is a software question, and potentially still a list question), but we'll have to see what other people think.

Comment: Just in case, on meta it was said that questions about software very specific to physics issues should be allowed [here](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/2825/2751) and [here](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/2898/2751), I hope people in power respect this ... And the list issue should not be misused to close this just for the heck of closing it either, not every question that asks about something which could potentially have more than one but still a small number of answers should be closable as a (big) list question.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks for the reminder. I think with another slight rephrasing that I just made, it's okay.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky thanks for making the edit instead of closing it :-)

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/104805/226902

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a free and powerful software I can recommend you [Cadabra](http://cadabra.phi-sci.com/). It is designed specially for the field theory calculations.

> Cadabra is a computer algebra system (CAS) designed specifically for
>   the solution of problems encountered in field theory. It has extensive
>   functionality for tensor computer algebra, tensor polynomial
>   simplification including multi-term symmetries, fermions and
>   anti-commuting variables, Clifford algebras and Fierz transformations,
>   implicit coordinate dependence, multiple index types and many more.
>   The input format is a subset of TeX. Both a command-line and a
>   graphical interface are available.