# Comparison between Cadabra and other Symbolic Computer Algebra software

Tags: quantum-field-theory, soft-question, computational-physics, software

Does anyone has some experience about working with [Cadabra](http://cadabra.phi-sci.com/) and it's (dis)advantage in comparison to other Symbolic Computer Algebra software such as Maple and Mathematica (physics package) in the field theory/gravity problems?

Comment: Since "Cadabra is a computer algebra system (CAS) designed specifically for the solution of problems encountered in field theory", it seems this is a perfectly legitimate question and is on-topic for the site according to the [recent discussion](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5603/). +1.

Comment: I would look to [Should we allow software questions? (take 3)](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3980/should-we-allow-software-questions-take-3) and earlier incarnation for deciding the topicality of this as this is a question about a third-party tool not a question about a numeric implementation. That said, it seems to be a compare and contrast which is to say opinion-based.

Comment: In fact I am not looking for the personal opinions. I would like to know more about internal functions and flexibility of them for defining and solving the real problems. For example, something like this paper: n3w4lit.jinr.ru/publish/Pepan_letters/panl_7_2009/05_sev.pdf‎

Comment: @dmckee no, the OP is not looking for personal opinion but expert knowledge, and as Emilio said such questions about software used exclusively by physicists are allowed per meta decision.

Comment: The latest Meta discussion (that Emilio links to) states *we cannot advise on libraries/languages/compilers/etc*. This question appears to be asking advice on a library/language and is thus off-topic.

Comment: Hi @Vahid, this question fits poorly on Phys.SE for various reasons e.g. it is _primarily opinion-based,_ and it is about software rather than an actual physics question. In particular, Phys.SE rarely provides software (and book) reviews.

Comment: @Qmechanic, thanks for your consideration. I accept you decision. But I would like to ask you where can I find an expert-based analysis about my question? In my first comment I mentioned a paper that compare these software. But unfortunately his paper has been published on 2009 and after that time these software have been changed a lot. In fact, I am looking for something like this paper but more update.

Comment: I just have found the below article that answer partly to my question. In fact, I am looking for this type of analysis that I think that fit on Phys.SE. :)    http://inspirehep.net/record/1282594

Comment: This software is now housed at https://cadabra.science, and any discussion about it which is considered off-topic here can be had at https://cadabra.science/qa/ . Am happy to help where possible.