# Software for calculating perturbation effects in general relativity

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations, computational-physics, software, linearized-theory

I need to evaluate the Einstein tensor/ Ricci tensor and others in a perturbed metric. Suppose my metric is

$g_{ab} =\eta_{ab} +h_{ab}$, where $\eta$ is the Minkowski metric, and $h$ is a small perturbation. I want to find the first order correction to the aforesaid metrics.

Is there any software/package that is capable of doing this kind of symbolic computations?

Comment: [xAct](http://www.xact.es/)

Comment: You can write this sort've thing quite easily into Mathematica or Maple

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/104805/226902 (cadabra)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While these sorts of things are obviously 'to taste', my preferred two are:

Mathematica with the [xAct](http://www.xact.es/) package with the [xTras](http://www.xact.es/xTras/index.html) addon. There is a useful tutorial on e.g. expanding perturbatively around AdS [here](http://www.xact.es/xTras/documentation/tutorial/AdSPerturbations.html).

The second option is to use [Cadabra](https://cadabra.science/). This is a wonderful program where everything is input and rendered directly in $\LaTeX$, and is very intuitive to a field theorist (it is built for supergravity calculations). This takes a bit of getting used to if you're a Mathematica fan, but in my opinion, it's worth it. It helps if you know a basic amount of python, but you barely need much.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you explore Sagemath, here you have some examples to browse.

https://sagemanifolds.obspm.fr/examples.html