# I am unable to find the RGTC package for Mathematica which is a pre-requisite for G. Compere's surface charges package, where should I look?

Tags: general-relativity, computational-physics, specific-reference, software

The link given everywhere is [this](http://www.inp.demokritos.gr/%7Esbonano/RGTC/) but it shows Error 404. I am unable to find it elsewhere. What should I do?

Comment: You may want to check out SAGE, mentioned in this answer :https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/127953/207455.  But this was asked recently. Have you checked Mathematica?

Comment: @SolarMike but the surface charge package is built upon RGTC and that is the one I need to use

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is related to software problems

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about particular software, not physics.

Comment: So, have you checked Mathematica and its website(s) and available downloads?

Comment: @G.Smith can you suggest some other place where I can post this?

Comment: @SolarMike as many as I could find. They all linked to the same place I have mentioned in the question

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @G.Smith alright

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might try [here.](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/4484/) There is a download link in upper right of page.