# Do anyone know a good software that where I can easily find the metric from the stress-energy tensor?

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations, metric-tensor, software, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I'm using SageMath but the obtainment of the metric from the stress-energy tensor is not trivial, i.e., it is not implemented in a predefined function.

Do anyone know a good software that where I can easily find the metric from a given stress-energy tensor with constant entries?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open source computer algebra systems for general relativity](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/160047/)

Comment: Not at all a duplicate, since no program can do as you ask. For instance if the stress-energy tensor is zero there are many metrics. Minkowski, a small gravitational plane wave travelling rightwards, a large gravitational plane wave travelling upwards, etc. How could a CAS know which you wanted?

Comment: Specifically, I'm looking for the metric of a constant magnetic or electric field in $\hat{z}$ direction. I know to obtain its stress-energy tensor, but I don't easily know how to obtain its metric.