# What is the metric of a constant electromagnetic (pure electric or pure magnetic) field?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, metric-tensor, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

For example, imagine a magnetic field $B_x$ directing in $\hat{x}$ direction filling all the space. What is its associated metric field?

I can construct the electromagnetic [stress-energy tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor) for this situation:

$T^{\mu\nu}=\frac{B_x^2}{2\mu_0}\begin{pmatrix}
 1  &  & &\\ 
 &  -1  & & \\ 
 &  &  1 &\\ 
 &  &  & 1
\end{pmatrix}$,

(the blank elements are zeros) and I could find the metric from it using Einstein's equation with the help of a  [CAS](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/189658/do-anyone-know-a-good-software-that-where-i-can-easily-find-the-metric-from-the), but this solving procedure seems complex for me.

Here in the community there are many questions about electromagnetic stress-energy tensor. But, up to my knowledge, none of them shows explicitly the metric of a constant electromagnetic field. Does anyone know a book or article that shows this?

Comment: In the book "Exact Solutions to Einstein's Field Equations", it is said that  the only conformally flat non-null solution of the (sourcefree) Einstein–Maxwell equations is $ds^2=(1-\lambda y^2)dx^2+(1-\lambda y^2)^{-1}dy^2+(1-\lambda z^2)^{-1}dz^2-(1-\lambda z^2)dt^2$, where $\lambda k^2=1$ and the electromagnetic field is $\sqrt{\kappa_0}F_{12}=\sqrt{2\lambda}\sin\beta$ and $\sqrt{\kappa_0}F_{43}=\sqrt{2\lambda}\cos\beta$, with $\kappa_0$ being Einstein’s gravitational constant. 

So, is this the metric for simultaneous non-null  $\vec{E}=E_x\hat{x}$ and $\vec{B}=B_x\hat{x}$?

Comment: It seems that the previous $k$ is related to the Robertson-Walker metric (I don't understand how).

Comment: Please, forgive my ignorance. How could this line element be comformally flat?

Comment: If $\vec B = B\hat x$ and $\vec E =\vec 0$ then isn't $T_{\mu\nu}=\frac{B^2}{2\mu_0}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & & &\\ & +1 & & \\ & &0 &\\ & & & 0\end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: Note that you can edit your own question.  Perhaps you would prefer to do that.  It would keep all of your thoughts in one place.

Answer (score 1):

The way you pose the question it seems you have in mind a solution with full translational symmetry in space, and rotational symmetry about the magnetic field direction at each point. I don't know if such a solution exists; if it does must be time-dependent: if the spacetime is static, then the extrinsic curvature of the spatial sections vanishes. The $tx$ component of the Einstein equation then implies that the $tx$ component of the stress energy tensor must vanish. But for a magnetic field in the $x$ direction, that component is $-B^2/2\ne0$.

A time-independent, stable solution exists that has translational symmetry in the direction of the magnetic field, and rotational symmetry about one axis. This is "Melvin's magnetic universe". The magnetic field energy is gravitationally bound, but does not collapse because of the magnetic pressure. The spatial geometry of this solution is strange. If I recall correctly, the circumference of a circle in a plane orthogonal to the symmetry axis goes to *zero* as the cylindrical radius goes to infinity.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'll verify the Melvin's magnetic universe. By the way, why do you expect that a solution with full translational symmetry in space, and rotational symmetry about the magnetic field direction at each point is time-dependet?

Comment: I added the explanation.

Comment: *That symmetry would imply that the spatial sections are flat* I don't follow you here...why?

Comment: I don't follow myself either. Sorry, I don't know what I was thinking. I'll replace my answer with an accurate one, with the same conclusion that the solution cannot be static.

Answer (score 0):

The stress-energy tensor associated to a vanishing electric field $\vec E=0$ with a magnetic field of the form $\vec B = B_0 \hat x$ is given by,

$$T^{\mu\nu} = \frac{B_0^2}{2\mu_0} \eta^{\mu\nu}.$$

By happenstance, I can recall a solution which exhibits a similar stress-energy tensor. If we consider a simple Randall-Sundrum brane, with the metric of the form,

$$ds^2 = dw^2 + e^{2A(w)}\left( dt^2 - dx^2 - dy^2 - dz^2\right)$$

which has an Einstein tensor (proportional to the stress-energy),

$$G_{\mu\nu} = -e^{2A}\eta_{\mu\nu}(3A''+6A'^2).$$

Thus, with the help of this additional dimension, we can have a brane whose stress-energy is precisely of the same form as for the constant magnetic field you presented. However, we must solve the differential equation,

$$3A''+6A'^2 = e^{2A}.$$

By making a substitution, $A(w) = \ln f(w)$ we arrive at the form,

$$f''(w)+\frac{f'(w)^2}{f(w)}=\frac13f(w)^3.$$

Mathematica is able to solve this, but it involves a messy inverse function involving trigonometric functions and elliptic functions. As such, I don't believe the solution, at least in these coordinates is pretty, but it certainly can be cast in the form presented, and exists.