# Metric tensor calculation tool?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, resource-recommendations, software

The Einstein field equations are

$G_{\mu\nu}+\Lambda g_{\mu\nu}=\kappa T_{\mu\nu}$

which would be easy enough to solve if not for all of the nonlinear dependencies on $g$ that the Einstein tensor $G$ has.

While solving these equations exactly by hand is extraordinarily difficult, I would think that there is some software (maybe a calculator or Python package or something) that I can use to compute the metric tensor given the stress-energy tensor. **Is there such a package or will I have to solve by hand?** Everywhere I’ve searched has turned up nothing.

Comment: If you know the Einstein tensor $G_{\mu\nu}$, it's not even possible to get the Riemann tensor $R_{\mu\nu}$, because the [Ricci decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_decomposition) says that you still have to specify the Weyl tensor.  You should read about the [initial value formulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_value_formulation_(general_relativity)) of GR.  The wiki article on [exact solutions to GR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_solutions_in_general_relativity) might also be helpful.

Comment: "Numerical relativity" is another search term that might get you what you want.  In short, it is Very Very Hard and how to do it better is a very active area of research.

Comment: There are probably numerical ways with some chaos inside given the non-linearity. That said, simplifying assumptions can me it easier to solve by hand. Schwarzchild found his solution by assuming a non-spinning, uncharged, spherically symmetric body. That led to a technique for understanding black holes.

Comment: related, Mathematica packages for GR: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/289491/

Comment: Yes there are some tools such as GRtensorII in http://grtensor.phy.queensu.ca/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open source computer algebra systems for general relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/160047/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solving the Einstein field equation is notoriously hard.  When Einstein originally calculated the GR contribution to Mercury's perihelion precession (the famous $\sim 43$ extra arc seconds per century), he did it using a perturbative solution.  The handful of known exact solutions have been found through simplifying assumptions and cleverness rather than systematic methods.  See, for example [Mueller & Grave 2009](https://arxiv.org/abs/0904.4184).

It is also challenging to set up numerical solutions.  The usual way we think about numerical differential equations is to set up some initial conditions for a system and step forward in time to see what the system is doing later.  But simultaneity is relative in relativity.  What do you mean by *now*, when you say this is the state of the spacetime *now*?  To define initial conditions, you are specifying a surface of simultaneity.  Then you take a step forward by $\Delta t$ to the next time, but the size of that step might be different in one spatial location compared to another due to time dilation.  And that's before you have to worry about what to do with coordinate and curvature singularities.

These issues have been slowly worked out over the years.  There is often a ton of pen and paper theoretical work just to get things in a form that you can even enter into a computer.

The most comprehensive numerical relativity package is the [Einstein Toolkit](https://einsteintoolkit.org/index.html), which is a stand alone code base for doing numerical relativity calculations.  It is the standard used by most active numerical relativity researchers.

A nifty related project is [NRPy+](https://blackholesathome.net/nrpy.html), which is a translation tool of sorts. It takes (more) human readable tensor notation equation input in `SymPy` and outputs optimized `C` code blocks that can be used with `EinsteinToolkit` to set up specific problems.